# How to Access attached property set on parent control from child control instance

Tags: wpf

I have a Canvas and inside the canvas i have a button.

From the button instance i have set the `Canvas.Left` attached property.

Now, from the button instance i have to access the value of the `Cavas.Left` attached property from code behind.

How can i achieve this ?

Ideally it should be done like :

Canvas.SetLeft(buttonInstance,value) and accessed like 
Canvas.GetLeft(buttonInstance) .. but i am not getting the value i have set. what whould be the cause of it.

Thanks

Comment: Post code to show us how you are setting the value and how you are trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `button1` as the name of your button. This allows you to do the following:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(button1, 100);
```

Comment: Now from button1 instance i want to access the value, how can i do this ? Canvas.GetLeft(button1) ?

Comment: @user2565258 Yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

By access, if you mean to read the value for the Canvas.Left property set for button.

```
Canvas.GetLeft(buttonInstance);
```

Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN page for more reading on Attached Properties.